# Unable to play music from using avplayer in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, avplayer

I am uploading music to server by converting it to **NSData**. When i upload the file to server then i also save it to document directory.So when i pass the url of any other music file other than i uploaded then it plays music.But when i try to play music file which i uploaded then it does not play the music.Below is the code for that.

**Code for play music**

```
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:fileURL];
        AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
        player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
        [player play];
```

Comment: might be your file url corrupted. can you show me the  how to set fileURl of document directory file and how did you get this

Comment: Can you provide the uploaded url for audio file ?

Comment: I am able to play the file on browser.@BhadreshMulsaniya @Nitin

Answer (score 0):

it may help you

```
 AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:fileURL options:nil];
  NSArray *keys     = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.indexValue]];
  [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:
    ^{
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(),
    ^{
    /* IMPORTANT: Must dispatch to main queue in order to operate on the AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem. */

    if (![[keys objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.indexValue]])
    {
    }
    // NSLog(@"&______________________________________________NOreturned");

    playerItem =  [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    if (!player)
    {
    player=nil;
    }
    player=[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    [player play];//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

  });
    }];

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a redundant reinitialization for  the  `player` object.

Do not forget to subscribe for notifications, for instance :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

As it was said in comments, download via browser the file using its URL and try to play by regular player.

Or create asset, and asks about it's tracks, duration, playable state.

```
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:_videoURL options:nil];

    NSArray *requestedKeys = @[@"tracks",@"playable",@"duration"];
    __weak typeof(self) wSelf = self;

    [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:requestedKeys completionHandler:
     ^{ 

          for (NSString *thisKey in requestedKeys) {
             NSError *error = nil;
              AVKeyValueStatus keyStatus = [asset statusOfValueForKey:thisKey error:&error];
              if (keyStatus == AVKeyValueStatusFailed) {



               //Failed here 
               //return
             }
            }

           if (!asset.isPlayable) {
              //not playable....
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice you use `AVAudioPlayer` for playing mp3. And I show you my two swift examples.

The first example when `AVAudioPlayer` plays mp3 file from `NSData`

```
  var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    func playFromCore() {
        let object = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.first as! Song
        let file = object.file // This is NSData
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: file, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3, error: nil)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
```

The second example when `AVAudioPlayer` plays `NSURL`

```
func playMusic() {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("89", withExtension: "mp3")!
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: nil)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Comment: I am using objective c.So please suggest something in objective-c

Comment: @deepakkumar I am sorry, I don't know Objective-C, but my example works because this snippet from my application in App Store.